# PHP SSH2: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Tags: php, windows, apache, ssh, phpseclib

I have a portable version of Apache and php7 on windows phpseclib1.0.7 . I wanted to expand the lib in order to utilize ssh.
using the stock script from the website for testing

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('-Redacted-');
if (!$ssh->login('-Redacted-', '-Redacted-')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->read('username@username:~$');
$ssh->write("sudo ls -la\n");
$output = $ssh->read('#[pP]assword[^:]*:|username@username:~\$#', 
NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX);
echo $output;
if (preg_match('#[pP]assword[^:]*:#', $output)) {
    $ssh->write("password\n");
    echo $ssh->read('username@username:~$');
}
?>
```

Even with the lack of information it should throw an error but instead it gives me

```
PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in 
C:\Users\-Redacted-\Desktop\Apache2.2\htdocs\Net\SSH2.php on line 2358
```

Here is the SSH2.php starting at line 2351

```
if (isset($this->keyboard_requests_responses)) {
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_prompts; $i++) {
if (strlen($response) < 4) {
return false;
}
extract(unpack('Nlength', $this->_string_shift($response, 4)));
// prompt - ie. "Password: "; must not be empty
Line 2358----  $prompt = $this->_string_shift($response, $length);
//$echo = $this->_string_shift($response) != chr(0);
foreach ($this->keyboard_requests_responses as $key => $value) {
if (substr($prompt, 0, strlen($key)) == $key) {
$responses[] = $value;
break;
}
}
}
}
```

does anyone have any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: Can you ping the remote host ?

Comment: are your sure your server ssh open is open?

Comment: putty works just fine with remote host.

Comment: Two things would help. (1) What version of phpseclib are you running? I don't know what line 2358 is and I checked on 1.0.0 - 1.0.7 and didn't find a line 2358 that it could timeout on. Also, (2) can you post the log file? You can get it by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2)` at the top of the file and then `$ssh->getLog()` later. Since it's not clear what line it is timing out on I'd try to figure that out first, before trying to get the logs. Like maybe do `echo 'THIS FAR';` after each `$ssh->read()` or something to see which one is being called..

Comment: phpseclib1.0.7 ----- line 2358    $prompt = $this->_string_shift($response, $length);

Comment: In line 2413, there's this: "*maybe phpseclib should force close the connection after x request / responses?  unless something like that is done there could be an infinite loop of request / responses*. I think that's the issue. The password is failing so phpseclib so phpseclib is trying it using keyboard-interactive auth. But the server isn't responding with `NET_SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE` or `NET_SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_SUCCESS` - it's responding with `NET_SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_INFO_REQUEST` over and over again, so phpseclib is looping. I'll see if I can put in PR to change this.

Comment: Line 2413: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/1.0.7/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php#L2413

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't reach www.domain.tld, first of all, you have to be sure that www.domain.tld is reachable from your system.
you can wrap your code in a try-catch block to get an error

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');
try{
 $ssh = new Net_SSH2('-redacted-');
 if (!$ssh->login('-redacted-', '-redacted-')) {
     exit('Login Failed');
      }

 echo $ssh->read('username@username:~$');
 $ssh->write("sudo ls -la\n");
 $output = $ssh->read('#[pP]assword[^:]*:|username@username:~\$#', 
 NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX);
 echo $output;
 if (preg_match('#[pP]assword[^:]*:#', $output)) {
     $ssh->write("password\n");
     echo $ssh->read('username@username:~$');
 }catch(\Exception $ex){echo "You got an error".$ex->getMessage();}
?>
```

if your are sure that host is reachable you can expand maximum timout like this :

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

if you are sure that your host is correct you can check that your host ssh port is open and work correclty?

Comment: I left the information generic since I am not allowed to give out the connection details. I can putty the host fine.

Comment: @MoonEater916 - it'd be interesting to see the PuTTY logs - you can get them by going to PuTTY -> Session -> Logging and checking the "SSH packets" radio button. Then connect as usual. I have an idea what the issue is (which, among other things, involves you logging in with the wrong PW) but the logs would help confirm this.